# Accelerate Sony Vegas Studio with ATI/NVIDIA?

Tags: video, encoding, sony-vegas, acceleration

Is there a way to accelerate the encoding in Sony Vegas Studio via GPU (ATI/NVIDIA)? ATI preffered!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin for](http://www.divideframe.com/?p=gpudecoder) Sony Vegas Pro to accelerate decoding ( GPU Decode ). However, I can't seem to find one for encoding, for Sony Vegas Studio